# What paper type should be used for charcoal drawing?

Tags: paper, charcoal, sketching, graphite

I have problems in blending and getting smooth texture when I use my charcoal pencil on a **Monte Marte Jumbo Drawing Pad**.

I have **Strathmore** but yet to try it out.

| [image: Graphite] | [image: Charcoal] |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Related: [How do I get a blur (blended) effect in pencil drawings?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/532/how-do-i-get-a-blur-blended-effect-in-pencil-drawings)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What's the difference between drawing paper and regular paper?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/477/whats-the-difference-between-drawing-paper-and-regular-paper)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (this one was closed as a dupe of the last thread, but seems a little more specific: [How do I blend charcoal enough to make it look like a skin surface?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/how-do-i-blend-charcoal-enough-to-make-it-look-like-a-skin-surface)

Comment: Hi Adriel, if the information in any of these Q&As doesn't solve your problem, please let us know in a comment. Welcome to Arts & Crafts! (By the way, with Strathmore you mean one of their charcoal pads?)

Comment: @Joachim thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Were you able to find what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

I did and eventually the Strathmore paper was thick and smooth and its great for charcoal.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I closed your question as a duplicate of the one I think comes closest to what you were looking for.